# Property "RowSource" Fails to Display on Combo Box

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

If I set the `.RowSource` property of a ListBox to a **Named Range** then in both the VBA display of the UserForm and the Excel display of the UserForm the row sources can be selected. However, with the ComboBox I only see this on the VBA display. If after setting the `.RowSource` property I try to `.AddItem` to the ComboBox object I get `run time error 70, permission denied`.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With pres_unit
        .AddItem "kPa"
        .AddItem "bar"
    End With
End Sub
```

How can I use a named range as a source for the drop down options of a ComboBox?

[image: Excel screenshot of UserForm]

[image: VBA screenshot of UserForm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `NamedRange` for a single Column, you can use the `List` property of the **ComboBox**:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()      

' create the Named Range "myNameRange" 
' you can manually (or with variables) modify the Range("B2:B10") in "Sheet1"
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "myNameRange", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B10")

With pres_unit
    .List = Range("myNameRange").value
    'disallows user input, only values from list
    .Style = fmStyleDropDownList
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: ++ Nice. Once small addition to the code. Add `.AddItem "Blah Blah"` after  `.List = Range("myNameRange").value` to show how it works :)

Comment: This works well, thank you! Now if I try to set the Locked property of the ComboBox to True then the ComboBox doesn't display options. I only want the User to be able to select from the possible options, not type their own option in. How might I do this?

Comment: @DavidOllodart use the `.Style = fmStyleDropDownList` , see edited answer